# Многопоточное подключение к SSH

Tags: c#, многопоточность, ssh

Наставьте на путь истинный, подскажите, что можно сделать/почитать по этому поводу?

Есть список объектов типа IP.

```
class IP
{
    public string host;
    public string login;
    public string password;
}
```

И метод, который перебирает этот список в параллельном цикле, в котором происходит подключение к SSH.

```
public void Cycle()
{
  int port = 22;

  Parallel.ForEach(ipList, ipObject =>
  {
       string ip = ipObject.host;
       string login = ipObject.login;
       string password = ipObject.password;

       SshConnect(ip, port, login, password);
  });
}
```

Метод `SSHConnect` реализован с помощью библиотеки Renci.SSHNet. Выглядит следующим образом:

```
private bool SshConnect(string host, int port, string login, string password)
 {
     bool flag = true;
     try
     {
          var client = new SshClient(host, port, login, password);
          client.Connect();
          client.Disconnect();
     }
     catch
     {
          flag = false;
     }
     return flag;
 }
```

Все бы ничего, но скорость перебора и подключения к SSH ужасно медленная. Что можно сделать, чтобы увеличить скорость?

P.S. Раньше у меня был алгоритм, который работал, как минимум, в 2 раза быстрее этого.

В нем я использовал один поток, в котором находился цикл, перебирающий список и в этом же потоке создавалось определенное количество других потоков, которые в свою очередь обрабатывали эти элемента списка.

На другом форуме сказали, что так делать нежелательно и немного почитав, я решил попробовать `Paralel.ForEach`, но результат не оправдал ожиданий.

Comment: тэг языка добавь

Comment: А сам метод `SshConnect()` вообще имеет возможность работы в параллельных потоках?

Comment: Не знаю. Я только начал изучать параллельное программирование.
Как это определить?

Answer (score 4):

Основное время при подключении по ssh тратит не процессор, а сеть - пакет TCP SYN слишком долго идет до сервера и обратно. В таких условиях надо и правда создавать как можно больше потоков, `Paralel.ForEach` же ограничивает их число.

---

У вас есть список ssh-серверов, с которыми надо что-то сделать - или вы сканируете сеть?

Во втором случае можно сделать оптимизацию. Сначала можно проверить, открыт ли порт 22 - а уже потом подключаться по ssh там, где он открыт.

Это можно сделать параллельно, но вовсе без потоков, при помощи асинхронного программирования:

```
var taskList = ipList.Select(async ipObject => {
  try {
    using (var c = new TcpClient()) await c.ConnectAsync(ipObject.host, 22);
    retrun ipObject;
  } catch { return null; }
}).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(taskList);
ipList = taskList.Select(task => task.Result).Where(ipObject => ipObject != null).ToList();

// Теперь в ipList остались только хосты, которые отвечают на порту 22
```